# Positioning image and text

Tags: html, css

I have an image and text in a container `div`.

I want the `img` floated left and the text center of the page but I can't do it. The image and the text both have their own `div`s.

How can I do that?

Here is my CSS and HTML:

```css
 #ImageDiv {
   position: relative;
   margin: auto;
   width: 250px;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
 }
 #TextDiv {
   position: relative;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
   float: left;
 }
 #ContainerDiv {
   text-align: center;
   width: auto;
   height: 104px;
   background-color: rgb(252, 251, 249);
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-style: inset;
   border-width: 2px;
   font-size: 22px;
   color: rgb(46, 84, 0);
   margin: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="ContainerDiv">
  <div id="ImageDiv">
    <img style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;" src="imagePath" alt="Alternate Text" />
  </div>
  <div id="TextDiv">
    <h5>Some Text Goes Here...</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A design image would help here but I suspect that you will have to use absolute positioning on one of the two child divs.

Comment: I tried to use absolute positioning on imageDiv. But after that, i cant put the text to the center of the page, i dont understand why

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.net, copy your code there, save it, and come back - this will help to see what you're after

Comment: have you tried using a table?

Comment: In some sense [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mxomh49q/) is in the centre of the page

Comment: Ok, i made a little mistake there. I made the ImageDiv absolute positioning. The İmaheDiv's margin: auto; and the TextDiv's float: left; was unnecessary. I took them off and it solved my problem. Thanks anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option which positions the text div

```css
#ContainerDiv {
    position: relative;    position: relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden; /* quick clearfix */

}

#ImageDiv{
    float:left;
}

#ImageDiv img {
    display: block;
}

#TextDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div id="ContainerDiv">
        <div id="ImageDiv"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-150-150-1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text" /> </div>
        <div id="TextDiv"><h5>Some Text Goes Here...</h5></div>
</div>
```